# How to register for reCAPTCHA V2 instead of Enterprise

Tags: recaptcha

For a wordpress plugin I am required to register for reCAPTCHA V2 thereafter I should receive a site and secret key. But I am only able to register for reCAPTCHA Enterprise where I am given only one key. Is there a way to explicitly register for V2?

Comment: Can you please provide additional information about what you're trying to do. Which plugin exactly, how are you attempting to register for reCAPTCHA, what is the exact error/issue you're experiencing, what you've already tried, etc